# Forwarding over two routers

Tags: routes, webserver, nat, cisco, forwarding

I am trying to solve an issue with accessing web-server over two routers. Looking on the diagram accessing is following:

```
case 1: computer - dir-100 - 4321 - web-server 1 - accessible
case 2: internet - dir-100 - web-server 2 - accessible
case 3: internet - dir-100 - 4321 - web-server 1 - is not accessible
```

The configuration on cisco is like pass everything:

```
ip nat inside source list INTERNET_NAT_ACCESS-LIST interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0 overload
ip nat outside source static 192.168.0.103 192.168.3.1
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 ISP-DNS
ip route ISP-DNS 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1
!
!
ip access-list extended INTERNET_NAT_ACCESS-LIST
 permit ip host 192.168.3.0 any
```

The configuration on D-Link DIR-100 is a standard but added routing to web-server 1:

```
Interface(ISP) - Destination(192.168.3.2) - Mask (255.255.255.255) - Gateway(192.168.0.103)
```

Also for case 2: I have added port forwarding, without it case 2 is not working obviously

When I tried set port forwarding on DIR-100 to `192.168.0.103` which is input interface of cisco router, there is no luck to access web-server 1 from internet

NAT on cisco:

```
r1#show ip nat translations 
Pro  Inside global         Inside local          Outside local         Outside global
---  ---                   ---                   192.168.3.1           192.168.0.103
```

Interfaces:

```
r1#show ip int brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0/0   192.168.3.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0/1   unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1/0   192.168.0.103   YES DHCP   up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0       unassigned      YES NVRAM  down                  down    
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

any thoughts? Thanks.

[image: network diagram]

Answer (score 0):

As by default cisco routers configured to DENY ANY traffic if it wasn't precisely configured in my configuration it was also denied despite

```
ip nat outside source static 192.168.0.103 192.168.3.1
```

So if you want to make a hole to some particular point you MUST write it in such a straight fashion, in my case to allow port forwarding to the web-server

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.3.2 80 192.168.0.103 80
```